# How to change the identity pool id of an App in Amazon Mobile Analytics console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-mobile-analytics

I have already set up Amazon's S3 and DynamoDB in an iPhone App so I have Cognito going and an identity pool with the proper roles / policies set up.

I am now trying to also use the Analytics, but cannot work it out.

I have set up an app in Mobile Analytics but [According to this PDF from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/mobile-analytics-ug.pdf)
I can change the pool id / or set up a new app with a choice of an ID. I cannot do that.

How Do I change the pool id for an existing app set up in Mobile Analytics?

To make the question even simpler.  How do I get [this view in the console?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/images/existing-pool-no-default-initial.png)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to ask a question, you usually stumble across the answer.

So my existing Cognito identity pool was an EU pool.

Mobile Analytics are currently only supported in US East. Or to put a positive spin on that are "Global". :-)

In any case I am guessing that you don't get the drop down choice at all if you don't have an identity pool for US East. It would be better if there was a hint there instead.

In Cognito as I have only ever had one identity I did not realise that you only saw the pool identities based on your region choice on the top right. So I worked out that there was a newly created id pool there.

Once I worked out this I could then add a role to the automatically created identity pool id and then use this ID in my app.

Answer (score 0):

The Cognito Identity Pool dropdown provided in the Integration Steps view of the Amazon Mobile Analytics Console is used purely to populate the code samples.

You can use any identity pool that has the following permission in its associated role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Action": [
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Per [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198284/1443896) you can actually use a Cognito Identity Pool from any supported Cognito region by manually specifying a different region for your CredentialsProvider. Just be sure to keep the Analytics region US-EAST-1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AWS console, choose mobile Analytics.

**1. choose "*Manage Apps*"**
[image: choose "Manage Apps"].

**2. Click on "*View Integration Steps*"**
[image: Click on "View Integration Steps"]

**3. Select the Congnito pool**
[image: Select the Congnito pool]